# Thunderbolt - HDMI - TV display switching problems

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I have a Thunderbolt to HDMI to TV set up.

On occasion it just starts switching the TV display on and off.

I have not been able to determine the root cause.

Looking in the Console just confirms the Display switching, but I do not see the reason.

I can not isolate the problem since it is sporadic, but started recently.

I have tested the HDMI cable (not the Thunderbolt adapter) otherwise and it works fine.

I tired all 3 of the HDMI inputs on the TV without success.

<sub>5/13/14 11:44:44.439 PM WindowServer[108]: Display added
    5/13/14 11:44:44.439 PM WindowServer[108]: Display removed
    5/13/14 11:44:44.439 PM WindowServer[108]: Displays mirrored
    5/13/14 11:44:37.584 PM WindowServer[108]: hw_mirror_device_if_possible: windowserver picks master 0x4273c00 as primary (driver did not pick)
    5/13/14 11:44:37.584 PM WindowServer[108]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0: Startup Mode 1440 x 900, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80000000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
    5/13/14 11:44:37.585 PM WindowServer[108]: Display mode changed
    5/13/14 11:44:37.585 PM WindowServer[108]: Display added
    5/13/14 11:44:37.585 PM WindowServer[108]: Display removed
    5/13/14 11:44:37.585 PM WindowServer[108]: Displays mirrored
    5/13/14 11:44:37.586 PM WindowServer[108]: Display 0x04273c00: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 17 modes available
    Master in mirror set; Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model 9cf0, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
    UUID 0x933c106c08bc09aaf750c2a74a119def, ColorProfile { 5, "Color LCD Calibrated"}</sub>

UPDATE:

It is not the TV sleep mode since it goes for 10 minutes or more then it starts switching on/off...on/off like crazy (see Console report), then it eventually stops and goes on for another while.

More Update:

So I am trying to narrow it down:
This is only a small extract of a long list in what is it doing in very rapid fashion. I am not touching anything but it keeps switching the display mode?
It says Received display connect changed? So my question is "Received from whom?" The TV, or the Thunderbolt/HDMI plug? Where do the all different display ### come from?

<sub>5/15/14 10:45:59.804 AM WindowServer[108]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4273c00
    5/15/14 10:45:59.853 AM WindowServer[108]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
    5/15/14 10:45:59.890 AM WindowServer[108]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
    5/15/14 10:46:07.425 AM WindowServer[108]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4273c00
    5/15/14 10:46:07.441 AM WindowServer[108]: Received display connect changed for display 0x44105d81
    5/15/14 10:46:07.443 AM WindowServer[108]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
    5/15/14 10:46:09.913 AM WindowServer[108]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4273c00
    5/15/14 10:46:09.964 AM WindowServer[108]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d</sub>

MBA 10.9.2

Comment: Buscar : check the manual for the TV and see if it has an auto-energy-saving feature, as this would explain why that is happening if it is being engaged (energy saver on, mac wakes it up, energy saver on, mac wakes it up, etc.). If that is the issue, disabling that feature is probably not going to be easy. :/

Comment: @chillin it would not do that repeatedly (on/off) with in seconds, then it stays on for 10 minutes (or more) then it does it again :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem Solved**.

After analyzing the Console reports:

```
5/19/14 4:41:03.605 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
```

I learned that the 0x04273c00 is my Build in Display for reference.

**After plug in Thunderbolt but TV is still OFF**

```
5/19/14 4:42:19.126 PM WindowServer[88]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4273c00
5/19/14 4:42:19.128 PM WindowServer[88]: Found 16 modes for display 0x04273c00 [16, 0]
5/19/14 4:42:19.175 PM WindowServer[88]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
5/19/14 4:42:19.177 PM WindowServer[88]: Found 23 modes for display 0x003f003d [23, 0]
5/19/14 4:42:19.177 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x003f003d changed state to online
5/19/14 4:42:19.199 PM WindowServer[88]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
5/19/14 4:42:19.200 PM WindowServer[88]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003e [1, 0]
5/19/14 4:42:19.243 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 16 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model 9cf0, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0x933c106c08bc09aaf750c2a74a119def, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
5/19/14 4:42:19.243 PM WindowServer[88]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x0000368b, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
5/19/14 4:42:19.243 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
5/19/14 4:42:19.243 PM WindowServer[88]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x0000368b, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
5/19/14 4:42:19.243 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2465, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
5/19/14 4:42:19.243 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: GL mask 0x2; bounds (-1920, 0)[1920 x 1080], 23 modes available
Active, on-line, enabled, Vendor 4d10, Model 4176, S/N 0, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0x7644772bda565e1fbf3db170bfc97c32, ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}
5/19/14 4:42:19.244 PM Dock[272]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x44105d81
5/19/14 4:42:19.244 PM Dock[272]: uuid_callback_master: failed to retrieve UUID for display 0x44105d81 (1001) (invariant failure)
5/19/14 4:42:19.245 PM Dock[272]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x44105d81
5/19/14 4:42:19.245 PM Dock[272]: uuid_callback_master: failed to retrieve UUID for display 0x44105d81 (1001) (invariant failure)
5/19/14 4:42:19.494 PM WindowServer[88]: CGError post_notification(const CGSNotificationType, void *const, const size_t, const bool, const CGSRealTimeDelta, const int, const CGSConnectionID *const, const pid_t): Timed out 0.250 second wait for reply from "Google Chrome" for synchronous notification type 100 (kCGSDisplayWillReconfigure) (CID 0x103ab, PID 10899)
5/19/14 4:42:19.550 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0: Mode 1920 x 1080, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x8000200b, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
5/19/14 4:42:19.666 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1: Mode 1920 x 1080, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80002000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
5/19/14 4:42:19.746 PM WindowServer[88]: hw_mirror_device_if_possible: windowserver picks master 0x44105d81 as primary (driver did not pick)
5/19/14 4:42:19.752 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0: Startup Mode 1920 x 1080, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x8000200b, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
5/19/14 4:42:19.752 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1: Startup Mode 1920 x 1080, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80002000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
5/19/14 4:42:19.752 PM WindowServer[88]: Display mode changed
5/19/14 4:42:19.752 PM WindowServer[88]: Display added
5/19/14 4:42:19.752 PM WindowServer[88]: Display removed
5/19/14 4:42:19.752 PM WindowServer[88]: Displays mirrored
5/19/14 4:42:19.754 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: GL mask 0x2; bounds (0, 0)[1920 x 1080], 23 modes available
Master in mirror set; Main, Active, on-line, enabled, Vendor 4d10, Model 4176, S/N 0, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0x7644772bda565e1fbf3db170bfc97c32, ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}
5/19/14 4:42:19.754 PM WindowServer[88]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: acquired display context (0x7fc8eb427030) - enabling OpenGL
5/19/14 4:42:19.755 PM WindowServer[88]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x0000368b, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
5/19/14 4:42:19.755 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1920 x 1080], 16 modes available
Hardware mirror of 0x44105d81; on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model 9cf0, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0x933c106c08bc09aaf750c2a74a119def, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
5/19/14 4:42:19.755 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2944, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
5/19/14 4:42:19.755 PM WindowServer[88]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x0000368b, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
5/19/14 4:42:19.755 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2945, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
5/19/14 4:42:19.806 PM WindowServer[88]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x44105d81 device: 0x7fc8eb427030  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
5/19/14 4:42:19.817 PM WindowServer[88]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: acquired display context (0x7fc8eb4253c0) - enabling OpenGL
5/19/14 4:42:21.176 PM WindowServer[88]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
5/19/14 4:42:21.200 PM WindowServer[88]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
5/19/14 4:42:21.227 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:42:21.228 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:42:21.277 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:42:21.278 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:42:21.293 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:42:21.295 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:42:21.333 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:42:21.334 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:42:21.576 PM WindowServer[88]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
5/19/14 4:42:21.624 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:42:21.625 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:42:21.677 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:42:21.678 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:42:21.706 PM WindowServer[88]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
5/19/14 4:42:21.761 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:42:21.763 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:42:21.804 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:42:21.805 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, “Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
```

**Turn TV ON and select HDMI as Input source**

```
5/19/14 4:46:30.666 PM WindowServer[88]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4273c00
5/19/14 4:46:30.668 PM WindowServer[88]: Found 16 modes for display 0x04273c00 [16, 0]
5/19/14 4:46:30.730 PM WindowServer[88]: Received display connect changed for display 0x44105d81
5/19/14 4:46:30.730 PM WindowServer[88]: Found 1 modes for display 0x44105d81 [1, 0]
5/19/14 4:46:30.730 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81 changed state to offline
5/19/14 4:46:30.731 PM WindowServer[88]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
5/19/14 4:46:30.732 PM WindowServer[88]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003e [1, 0]
5/19/14 4:46:30.758 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1920 x 1080], 16 modes available
Hardware mirror of 0x44105d81; Main, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model 9cf0, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0x933c106c08bc09aaf750c2a74a119def, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
5/19/14 4:46:30.758 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2944, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
5/19/14 4:46:30.758 PM WindowServer[88]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x0000368b, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
5/19/14 4:46:30.758 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2945, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
5/19/14 4:46:30.759 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (0, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
Master in mirror set; off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff, ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}
5/19/14 4:46:30.759 PM WindowServer[88]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x0000368b, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
5/19/14 4:46:30.827 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0: Mode 1440 x 900, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80004000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
5/19/14 4:46:30.830 PM WindowServer[88]: WSDisplayPipeTransactionEnd returned error e00002be
5/19/14 4:46:30.831 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0: Startup Mode 1440 x 900, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80004000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
5/19/14 4:46:30.831 PM WindowServer[88]: Display mode changed
5/19/14 4:46:30.832 PM WindowServer[88]: Display added
5/19/14 4:46:30.832 PM WindowServer[88]: Display removed
5/19/14 4:46:30.832 PM WindowServer[88]: Displays mirrored
5/19/14 4:46:30.833 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 16 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model 9cf0, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0x933c106c08bc09aaf750c2a74a119def, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
5/19/14 4:46:30.834 PM WindowServer[88]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x0000368b, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
5/19/14 4:46:30.834 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
5/19/14 4:46:30.834 PM WindowServer[88]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x0000368b, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
5/19/14 4:46:30.834 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2465, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
5/19/14 4:46:30.834 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2466, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff, ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}
5/19/14 4:46:30.840 PM WindowServer[88]: WSDisplayPipeTransactionEnd returned error e00002be
5/19/14 4:46:30.859 PM WindowServer[88]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x04273c00 device: 0x7fc8eb4253c0  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
5/19/14 4:46:32.192 PM WindowServer[88]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4273c00
5/19/14 4:46:32.194 PM WindowServer[88]: Found 16 modes for display 0x04273c00 [16, 0]
5/19/14 4:46:32.248 PM WindowServer[88]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
5/19/14 4:46:32.250 PM WindowServer[88]: Found 23 modes for display 0x003f003d [23, 0]
5/19/14 4:46:32.250 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x003f003d changed state to online
5/19/14 4:46:32.261 PM WindowServer[88]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
5/19/14 4:46:32.261 PM WindowServer[88]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003e [1, 0]
5/19/14 4:46:32.327 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1440 x 900], 16 modes available
Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model 9cf0, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0x933c106c08bc09aaf750c2a74a119def, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
5/19/14 4:46:32.327 PM WindowServer[88]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x0000368b, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
5/19/14 4:46:32.327 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2464, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
5/19/14 4:46:32.327 PM WindowServer[88]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x0000368b, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
5/19/14 4:46:32.327 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2465, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
5/19/14 4:46:32.327 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: GL mask 0x2; bounds (-1920, 0)[1920 x 1080], 23 modes available
Active, on-line, enabled, Vendor 4d10, Model 4176, S/N 0, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0x7644772bda565e1fbf3db170bfc97c32, ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}
5/19/14 4:46:32.328 PM Dock[272]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x44105d81
5/19/14 4:46:32.328 PM Dock[272]: uuid_callback_master: failed to retrieve UUID for display 0x44105d81 (1001) (invariant failure)
5/19/14 4:46:32.329 PM Dock[272]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x44105d81
5/19/14 4:46:32.329 PM Dock[272]: uuid_callback_master: failed to retrieve UUID for display 0x44105d81 (1001) (invariant failure)
5/19/14 4:46:32.578 PM WindowServer[88]: CGError post_notification(const CGSNotificationType, void *const, const size_t, const bool, const CGSRealTimeDelta, const int, const CGSConnectionID *const, const pid_t): Timed out 0.250 second wait for reply from "Google Chrome" for synchronous notification type 100 (kCGSDisplayWillReconfigure) (CID 0x103ab, PID 10899)
5/19/14 4:46:32.654 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0: Mode 1920 x 1080, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x8000600b, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
5/19/14 4:46:32.772 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1: Mode 1920 x 1080, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80006000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
5/19/14 4:46:32.852 PM WindowServer[88]: hw_mirror_device_if_possible: windowserver picks master 0x44105d81 as primary (driver did not pick)
5/19/14 4:46:32.858 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0: Startup Mode 1920 x 1080, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x8000600b, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
5/19/14 4:46:32.858 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1: Startup Mode 1920 x 1080, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80006000, ioModeDepth 0x0, IOReturn 0x0
5/19/14 4:46:32.858 PM WindowServer[88]: Display mode changed
5/19/14 4:46:32.859 PM WindowServer[88]: Display added
5/19/14 4:46:32.859 PM WindowServer[88]: Display removed
5/19/14 4:46:32.859 PM WindowServer[88]: Displays mirrored
5/19/14 4:46:32.861 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: GL mask 0x2; bounds (0, 0)[1920 x 1080], 23 modes available
Master in mirror set; Main, Active, on-line, enabled, Vendor 4d10, Model 4176, S/N 0, Unit 1, Rotation 0
UUID 0x7644772bda565e1fbf3db170bfc97c32, ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}
5/19/14 4:46:32.861 PM WindowServer[88]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: acquired display context (0x7fc8eb427030) - enabling OpenGL
5/19/14 4:46:32.861 PM WindowServer[88]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x0000368b, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
5/19/14 4:46:32.861 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1920 x 1080], 16 modes available
Hardware mirror of 0x44105d81; on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model 9cf0, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
UUID 0x933c106c08bc09aaf750c2a74a119def, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
5/19/14 4:46:32.861 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x003f003f: GL mask 0x8; bounds (2944, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 3, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
5/19/14 4:46:32.861 PM WindowServer[88]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x0000368b, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
5/19/14 4:46:32.861 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2945, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
5/19/14 4:46:32.862 PM WindowServer[88]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
5/19/14 4:46:32.869 PM WindowServer[88]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
5/19/14 4:46:32.926 PM WindowServer[88]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x44105d81 device: 0x7fc8eb427030  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
5/19/14 4:46:32.936 PM WindowServer[88]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: acquired display context (0x7fc8eb4253c0) - enabling OpenGL


5/19/14 4:46:33.614 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:46:33.616 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:46:33.727 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:46:33.729 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:46:33.811 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:46:33.813 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:46:33.871 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:46:33.873 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:46:34.248 PM WindowServer[88]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
5/19/14 4:46:34.261 PM WindowServer[88]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
5/19/14 4:46:34.310 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:46:34.311 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:46:34.368 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:46:34.370 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:46:34.401 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:46:34.402 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:46:34.419 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:46:34.420 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:46:34.681 PM WindowServer[88]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
5/19/14 4:46:34.728 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:46:34.729 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:46:34.781 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:46:34.782 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:46:34.812 PM WindowServer[88]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
5/19/14 4:46:34.861 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:46:34.862 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
5/19/14 4:46:34.904 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x44105d81: Unit 1; ColorProfile { 6, "HD 709-A"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
5/19/14 4:46:34.906 PM WindowServer[88]: Display 0x04273c00: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
```

It turns out that the communication between the TV and Mac is constantly trying to find another profile to use. Probably because the TV is telling Mac it is something else then Mac is telling it to do.

So looking in the profiles setting using the ColorSync and the available vs assigned profiles.

[image: HD SD]

The pic below show the solved solution with correct profiles.

[image: profiles]

The current profile was set to SD and not HD.

After changing the profile back to HD (High Definition) factory setting all was finally fine.

In plain English--Mac was telling the TV to use the SD profile (standard definition) normally not a problem but, the TV was replaying I am HD, and that is where the confusion came from.